# if $\limsup a_{n+1}/a_n = L < 1$, then $\sum a_n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I must demonstrate that, $\forall \{a_n\}$ define in $\mathbb{R}^{+}$, if
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = L < 1 \implies \sum a_n \text{ converges}$$

I know by the ratio test that if the limit is lower than $1$, the series will converges but what about the the superior limit?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Pick a meaningful title. Titles let people know quickly if they are able to help you. A title like this either wastes people's time (those who can't help but clicked through anyway) and loses people who might help (they simply ignore it and move along.) Help people help you.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of $\limsup$ there's for each $\epsilon>0$ an $N$ such that $a_{n+1}/a_n < L+\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$. From this follows that $a_n < a_N(L+\epsilon)$. Choosing $\epsilon<1-L$ will make $a_n$ limited by a geometric series.

It's also bounded below by $0$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $L < M < 1$ only if there is some $N \geq 1$ such that
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} < M
$$
for all $n \geq N$,
and
only if for all $p \geq 1$ we have
$$
a_{N+p} < a_{N}M^{p}
$$
by induction.
But $\sum_{p \geq 1}M^{p}$ converges;
so by comparison test
$\sum_{p \geq 1}a_{N+p}$ converges.

Comment: Why $M^p$? Where came the exposant?

Comment: It can be shown (try!) that If $L = \limsup_{n \to \infty}a_{n+1}/a_{n}$, then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $N \geq 1$ such that $a_{n+1}/a_{n} < L+ \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.

Comment: Use induction to solve your problem!